# Create multiple gridviews in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, visual-studio-2008

This is very interesting..

I want to have multiple gridviews in a panel. and the number of gridviews is not fixed..

So basically i think there should be no code in the .aspx page as i have to create the gridview in codebehind.

I have the code for 1 gridview in one panel.. where i define the grid view in the HTML page and populate it from the code behind.

Here is the code for that.. can any 1 please help me with the multiple gridviews...

this is on the .aspx page

```
       <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
      AllowSorting="True" CellSpacing="2" onsorting="GridView1_Sorting"
                    Width="100%" ForeColor="White" GridLines="None" 
                      ondatabound="GridView1_DataBound1">

       <Columns>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PolicyID") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PolicyID") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
      </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

this is the code behind

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Session["ConnectionStringSQL"].ToString()); 
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Policies.PolicyID, FROM Policies", connection);
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);

            sqlDa.Fill(dt);
            connection.Close();

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dt.Rows.Count; j++)
                {
                    policyID.Add(dt.Rows[j]["PolicyID"].ToString());

                }
                taskTable.Columns.Add("PolicyID");


                if (policyID.Count != 0)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < policyID.Count; k++)
                    {
                        DataRow tableRow = taskTable.NewRow();

                        tableRow["PolicyID"] = policyID[k];

                        taskTable.Rows.Add(tableRow);
                    }

                    Session["TaskTable"] = taskTable;

                    GridView1.DataSource = Session["TaskTable"];
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested, but this kind of thing should do it:

```
for (int i=0;i<5;i++) {
   GridView gv = new GridView();
   gv.DataSource = datasources[i];
   Page.Controls.Add(gv);
}
Page.DataBind();
```

Comment: As the comment below states, this would break if you were using masterpage

Answer (score 3):

Answer 1 works but just be careful if you are nesting this inside a master page, etc.. because it seems when you just bind directly to the PAGE you cant expect it to actually be placed inside your form tag.

I have a sproc that returns unknown number of different tables that i want dumped to the page so i put a Placeholder on the aspx page

and then used the loop thru my dataset

```
foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
{
    GridView gv = new GridView();
    gv.DataSource = table;
    gvPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(gv);
}
```

.....OR ....

```
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables.Count; i++)
{
           GridView gv = new GridView();
            gv.DataSource = ds.Tables[i];

            gvPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(gv);
}
```

.. and then bind to the placeholder so the tables end up inside my form within my child page, that is inside my master page

```
                gvPlaceHolder.DataBind();
```

Comment: For future reference, you should refer to other answers by poster's name (or some other unique criteria) rather than order number, as the order is based on voting score, which can change over time.

Answer (score 0):

```
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = obj.GetMedicalGridWithAge(MphID, ProductCode);
        if(ds.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            if (ds.Tables[1].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables.Count; i++)
                {

                    GridView gv = new GridView();
                    gv.ID = "gv" + (i + 1);
                    
                    gv.DataSource = ds.Tables[i];
                    gv.DataBind();
                    Panel1.Controls.Add(gv);
                    Label newLine = new Label(); newLine.Text = "<br/>";
                    Panel1.Controls.Add(newLine);

                }
            }
            else
            {
                GridView gv = new GridView();
                gv.ID = "gv" ;

                gv.DataSource = null;`
                gv.DataBind();
                Panel1.Controls.Add(gv);
            }
           
        }
```

Comment: Consider adding some text to your answer describing your solution. Your code snippet references objects declared elsewhere, so an explanation would really make the answer more useful.