# Can we create gridview as custom server control

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am trying to create simple grid view custom server control but it do not render.

namespace GridViewServerControl1 
{

```
[ToolboxData("<{0}:GridViewServerControl1 runat=server></{0}:GridViewServerControl1>")]
public class GridViewServerControl1 : CompositeControl
{
    GridView grd;

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        grd = new GridView();
        grd.ID = "rgd";


        this.Controls.Add(grd);
    }

    public override void RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        grd.RenderControl(writer);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You're adding a control and then rendering that same control.. that doesn't make sense. Look into this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187354/create-multiple-gridviews-in-code-behind. It's not exactly the same but you should be able to cipher it because you're smart ;)

Comment: Hi  Keyvan,                                                                                                        You are right but I am trying to do gridview as a custom sertver control. So I can use the dll of this server control in my another project. So that we need to create first and then render.

Comment: I'm incredibly experienced and well-versed with .NET Server controls, which are just C# code and can be used across multiple projects when you reference it. The problem above is that when you do this.Controls.Add(...), it automatically renders it so no need to call grd.RenderControl(writer);

Comment: Hi Keyvan,  if you know how to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' to type 'GridViewCustomControl.GridView'.

Comment: You could always make your GridViewCustomControl.GridView inherit System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView and then add in any customizations.